# C printf %a and %La

Tags: c, hex, printf, type-conversion

I have to reimplement `printf(3)` with `C` wihtout using any function that would do the conversion for me.

I thought I was done after I understood *thanks you to guys* how `%a` worked: [How %a conversion work in printf statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143651/how-a-conversion-work-in-printf-statement)

Then I realized I didn't understand how the `rounding` was done so I asked: [C printf float rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156185/c-printf-float-rounding?lq=1) and then thought that I was done after you helped me.

And now that `%a` is completely working just like the official one I thought `%La` would do exactly the same as `%a` but with a `long double` since the man only says:

> Modifier    a, A, e, E, f, F, g, G
>
> l (ell)     double (ignored, same behavior as without it)
> L           long double

And I discover that it outputs something completely different :'(

```
double a_double = 0.0001;
long double a_long_double = 0.0001;
printf("%a\n", a_double); #=> 0x1.a36e2eb1c432dp-14
printf("%La\n", a_long_double); #=> 0xd.1b71758e21968p-17
```

The `%a` result always begins with `1.` and now I don't understand at all what the `%La` is doing.

Could you help me understand the **process** that transforms `0.0001` to `0xd.1b71758e21968p-17` ?

EDIT: the part that I really don't understand is *why* `%a` always outputs something that starts with `1.` and not `%La` ?

EDIT2: To be even more precise: *why* does `%a` chooses to output `1. ...p-14` and `%La` chooses to output `d. ...p-17` ?

Comment: @Wintermute: But the whole output is rounded anyways... The two numbers that are printed are identical, but the chosen exponent is different.

Comment: @BillLynch Yes exactly my question!

Comment: @Wintermute: there are no differences between both numbers (beside the type): if you shift three bits one representation, you'll get the other.

Comment: @BillLynch: Your point is correct, just a nit-pick: the very purpose of %a is to NOT round the number to output!

Comment: @Wintermute: if you don't understand what's actually going on, please don't tell people that it's "floating point rounding errors".  There is no rounding error at work here; in fact, there is no rounding at all in the formatting.

Comment: Yes, yes, I retract the earlier comment; I thought it was something more simple than it was; that was my bad. One thing though: I never meant to say anything about rounding errors in formatting but in the machine representation. Those most certainly exist, although they're not the deciding factor I thought they were. (Or at all influential, taking a second look. T'was silly.)

Comment: On my FreeBSD AMD64 system, both the double and long double print as 0x1.a36e2eb1c432dp-14 so this is definitely something that is platform-dependent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any (finite, non-zero) floating point number has four distinct (and valid) hexadecimal floating-point representations:

1. one which highest hexadecimal digit is between 8 and F
2. another which highest hexadecimal digit is between 4 and 7
3. another which highest hexadecimal digit is 2 or 3
4. another which highest hexadecimal digit is 1

and they have successive increasing exponent values. You can pass from one to another using right shifting; this process might raise another digit to the right; there is no restriction in the C Standard about which representation you should use for the `%a` conversion.

With IEEE `float` (24-bit significand) or the usual double extended (64-bit significand, as with long double on i386 Linux), since the number of bits is divisible by 4, it is customary to use the first form for a normalized number, since it is the form which uses the fewest hexadecimal digits to fully represent the number (respectively 5 and 15 digits after the *hexadecimal* point `.`).

With IEEE `double` (53-bit significand), on the other hand, it looks better to use the fourth form and 13 hexadecimal digits after the point `.`: thus all the shown digits are actually representing data. The same would happen with IEEE *quad* (formally `binary128`, 113-bit significand), with 28 hexadecimal digits after the point.

These representations have also the nice property to match the in-memory representation of the numbers (this is why implementations are guided to do so by a footnote in the C99 standard.)

If we now look at your question, the first example (`double`) matches the guidelines above, having 1 as first digit and then 13 hexadecimal digits after the point.

The second example is more crafty. First a `double` constant is stored into a `long double` variable: depending on the compiler, the constant may be rounded to `double`'s precision (as it seems to be done here.) This means that the bits after the 53th will be all zeroes. Then the `%La` conversion used, also according to the guidelines above, thus choosing the first representation, start with a D (1101xxx in binary, to be compared with the 1.A which translated to 11010xxx); here too there are only 13 hexadecimal digits after the point since the compiler discarded printing the unnecessary zeroes (due to the rounding.)

Note that you cannot use `printf`'s `%a` conversion for `float`.

Comment: I had no idea! Thank you very much! Great answer btw.

Comment: Stellar answer! (expect 53th --> 53rd).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what aspect of the result it surprising you. If it's the difference in exponents and digits, that's just because of poor normalization. Note that for the first result you get a `1` before the radix point and for the second you get a `d` before it. Shift `d` right 3 bits and you have a `1`, and the lower bits (101) shift into the next position after the radix point, giving `a`, as expected.

As for how `0.0001` is transformed to `0xd.1b71758e21968p-17`, it's just a matter of finding the binary floating point value that's closest to the decimal number 0.0001. The mechanism for how that's done efficiently is somewhat involved, but the concept is simple.

Comment: Why does one outputs something that always starts with '1.' (%a) and not the other (%La) ?

Comment: @ItsASecret `binary64` has 52 explicit bits, and one implicit leading bit. 52 is divisible by 4 so it would be wasteful and annoying to print it as anything other than `1.xxxxxxxxxxxxx`. On the other hand, the extended-double you're dealing with has 64 bits in total for the significand and is not encoded with an implicit bit. To avoid overflowing into an additional character, most `printf` implementations print it as `x.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

Comment: @ItsASecret: I consider that an implementation flaw. From a standpoint of presenting the most useful information at a given precision specification, you want the digit before the radix point to always be in the range `8..f`. Printing a 1 results in gratuitous loss of precision. But it is a valid implementation.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: That only applies if the printing precision is sufficient to represent the value exactly (which is true with no explicit precision specified). If the caller limits the precision, it's undesirable to use a leading 1.

Comment: @R.. To display 53 bits, you are always "gratuitously" loosing at some  end; the benefit to use the right-aligned representation, and thus to loose at the left end being it always 1., is to match the in-memory representation. As a debugging tool, I consider it worth while. It also makes the implementation slightly easier if you are hand-coding, which again is a good point from a debugging perspective (I dislike chasing libc bugs.)

Comment: @AntoineL: I'm talking about what happens if you use `%.1a`. With a leading 1 you only get 5 bits of precision. With a leading digit in the range `8..f`, you have 8 bits.

Comment: @R.. About `%.1a`, I would agree with you, and for small precision I would do it your way, maxing the printed accuracy. But you'll agree with me that plain `%a` (or `%La`) is a different beast; and the fact is, the meaning of the precision, and its default value, are not at all homogeneous between the various floating-point specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what kind of machine you are working on here, but from the fact that you get a `0xd.`... result from `%La` implies that this is a machine where `long double` is an *unnormalized* floating poing type (such as 80-bit floats on an 8087).  With a *normalized* float, you will always get a result that starts with `0x1.`... as you were guessing, but for unnormalized floats, there are mulitple representations of the same number, which is what you are seeing here.

The whole point of the `%a` conversion spec is to allow for printing a binary floating point number as text in a way that it can later be read back with scanf that will result in a bit-identical value on a machine with the same floating point representation.

Comment: Oh ok I had no idea that this would have any impact, I am on OS X 10.10.2

Comment: Do not see in the C spec that the first digit must be  `0x1`  "A double argument representing a floating-point number is converted in the style [−]0xh.hhhh p±d, , where there is one hexadecimal digit (which is nonzero if the argument is a normalized floating-point number and is
otherwise unspecified) before the decimal-point character ..."  C11dr §7.21.6.1  8

Comment: The leading bit of 80-bit extended doubles is always 1 for normal numbers. The fact that this leading bit is explicit does not change the way it should be printed. The fact that 64 is divisible by 4 makes it tempting to print no more than 16 hex digits in total, though.

Comment: A footnote in the C spec specifically address a leading digit that is not 0 or 1: "Binary implementations can choose the hexadecimal digit to the left of the decimal-point character so that subsequent digits align to nibble (4-bit) boundaries".  This contradicts this answer`s "With a normalized float, you will always get a result that starts with 0x1."

Comment: @chux: while the spec doesn't formally require it, it would be a rather bizarre implementation that did extra work to produce something else for a floating point format with a hidden 1 bit.

Comment: @PascalCuoq:  Since the leading bit is explicit in 8087-extended, you can produce numbers where it is clear.  So the printf/scanf code needs to be able to deal with that case.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: more exactly, this is true for the 80-bit representation chosen by Intel and Motorola for the minimal-sized double extended format; one can conceptually think of another 80-bit format using one more bit in the significand, having the hidden bit in the external representation, being formally compliant with IEEE 754:1985, and being incompatible; of course the last point is the killer one. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisDodd Since the 387, all Intel FPUs raise an exception on values with the leading bit being 0 while the exponent indicates a normal number. This hardly counts as “dealing with”. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision

Comment: @ChrisDodd W.r.t chux remark: actually not bizarre at all: if you ever use the %a specifier against VAX D-float (56-bit significand, with one hidden bit), you are likely to have the first digit between 8 and F, because it is the natural way it aligns.

Comment: @ChrisDodd ".. printf code needs to be able to deal with that case. (leading bit 0)."  Although it is useful to indicate such unnormalized numbers, 1) the C spec does not require equal valued unnormalized (subnormal) / normalized numbers to display differently 2) In a test case, small unnormalized numbers near 0.0 do not print in a way that indicate "unnormal-ness".  Still maintain OP is not seeing an unnormalized number.

Comment: @chux: You are correct in that this is yet another place where the C spec is "broken" -- underspecified, allowing behavior that completely breaks the original intent of the feature in question.

Comment: @AntoineL: using "not bizarre" and "VAX D-float" together is an oxymoron :-)

Comment: @ChrisDodd: about the underspecification: actually, there are real reasons to not force any representation in the Standard; as you can read in the comments below http://stackoverflow.com/a/29171691/656988 there is a base contradiction in intent between "short" precision like `%.1a`, where you prefer to maximize the displayed accuracy; and `%a` (or hexadecimal floating-point like on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture) where you would prefer to align the *nibbles*. Ah, and sorry to exhibit again the bizarre :-D